# What is the XPM markup for rendering a Component Link Wrapper component with separate link text from Component Link?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I am trying to render fields of a schema called "Hyperlink" to be Experience Manager friendly.

The schema contains the following fields:

- Link Text (Type: Text)
- Internal Link (Type: Component Link)

This allows the editors to specify link text independent of the name of the linked component's name.

The best info I can find on how to render a Component Link for XPM/SiteEdit is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13682120/1284894

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="fieldname" -->
  <tcdl:ComponentField name="fieldname" index="${TemplateRepeatIndex}">
    <a href="#" tridion:href="@@Field@@" tridion:type="Component">@@Field@@</a>
  </tcdl:ComponentField>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

However, I have 2 fields to deal with, not one, where the href part comes from the Component  Link field and the link text comes from the Text field.  So what should the TCDL markup be in this scenario, or is switching to form editing mode the only way to edit the links with this content modeling approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing two fields means you need to have two different HTML elements that you can edit. So inline with that, you need two TCDL tags too.

The problem you are facing is a common one for which I only found one solution, and that is to add an additional bit of HTML which only shows up when in XPM (since there is no room in your anchor element to allow for editing both the link and the text), see my article on tridiondeveloper.com about having fun with XPM and Page Regions.

Comment: Great suggestion in Bart's article (http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/having-fun-with-experience-manager) to use CSS/JS to show one of the two fields.  Using this approach the problem can be solved by implementing a modal popup showing the Link Text field on hover of the component link.