# Not able to update url of a external url inside Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

I am not able to update the url of a external url field. Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

Here is the code I am using:

```
@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, Model.Component.Fields["Link"].EmbeddedValues[0]["ExternalLink"])
        <a href="@Model.Component.Fields["Link"].EmbeddedValues[0]["ExternalLink"].Value" class="learn-more">@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component, Model.Component.Fields["Link"].EmbeddedValues[0]["LinkText"])@Model.Component.Fields["Link"].EmbeddedValues[0]["LinkText"].Value</a>
```

Where "ExternalLink" is of type external url inside linked component "Link". Yes, I am able to update text inside url which is "LinkText" inside linked component "Link".

Below is the markup generated on the page:

```
<!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Link[1]/custom:ExternalLink[1]"} -->
        <a href="/Services/" class="learn-more"><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Link[1]/custom:LinkText[1]"} -->Find Out How</a>
```

Thanks.
Mukesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're missing a container element for the `<a>` element.

Add a `<div>` element around your hyperlink like this:

```
<div>
<!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Link[1]/custom:ExternalLink[1]"} -->
<a href="/Services/" class="learn-more"><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:HomePageWidget/custom:Link[1]/custom:LinkText[1]"} -->Find Out How</a>
</div>
```

Also check out these answers/posts:

1. https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5057/73
2. http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/having-fun-with-experience-manager

Comment: Thanks Albert, Your suggestion solved my problem by inserting a div tag around.